# remoteViews.setInt with opacity & hex-color code?

Tags: android, android-remoteview

I'm currently using this code to assign a color and opacity for a widget-textview:

```
remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.nextAlarm_textview, Color.parseColor(text_opacity + text_color));
```

Now I would like to do the same with the widget's background. Is that possible?
I tried something like this, but it's not working(invalid int):

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_relative, "setBackgroundColor", Integer.parseInt(background_opacity + background_color));
```

background_opacity is #FF, background_color is 000000 for example. Both are strings.

/edit:

```
> 08-24 19:28:48.964  15059-15059/com.widget E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.widget, PID: 15059
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "#FFFFFFFF"
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
            at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
     at com.widget.WidgetSettings$10.onClick(WidgetSettings.java:256)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Try removing the `#`.

Comment: Still the same error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "FF000000"`

Comment: Sorry -- replace the `#` with `0x`. Or, use the two-parameter version of `parseInt()`, where you specify the radix (`16`) directly, rather than using some prefix character.

Comment: Got it now. Replacing `#` with `0x` worked. `remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_relative, "setBackgroundColor", 0x7fffffff);` Thank you!